# How to send message from mosquitto broker to azure IOT hub

Tags: mosquitto, azure-iot-hub

I have installed mosquitto as a local broker. There are multiple devices which sends messages to the broker. I want that whatever message coming to mosquitto broker should be sent to azure IOT hub. Can anyone please refer to any document how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have several approaches:

- You can use one of the device client [SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks) (depending on which
  language you are using on your broker) to send data to IoT Hub
- You
  can use MQTT directly to communicate with IoT Hub, which will require
  that you do specific things described in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support)

(definitively recommend using the client SDK)